# Detect if an array contains integer or double

Tags: java, numbers

I'm working on a project that requires me to have a string representation of an array. The problem is having this duplicated code, that I'm sure can be refactored in some way, but I haven't found one yet.

```
private static String printDoubleArray(String title, double[] array){
    String result = title;
    for (double d : array) {
        result += d + " ";
    }
    return result;
}

private static String printIntArray(String title, int[] array){
    String result = title;
    for (int d : array) {
        result += d + " ";
    }
    return result;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have to live with the duplication. All JDK API do the same. What you should do however is use StringBuilders.

Comment: If you want to reduce duplicate, you can try using Arrays.toString(double[]) and Arrays.toString(int[]) ;)

Comment: the problem with Java Generics is it does not support primitives. for this reason I've seen many times people implement their own `IntSet`, `DoubleSet`,[in order to prevent the boxing overhead]... not only they cannot use `java.util.Collection`, they also have to duplicate the code, because of the same issue you have with primitives.

Comment: @rlbisbe: also, you should use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` to create `result`, it will probably be *much* more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use one of the methods [`Arrays.toString(...)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28boolean%5B%5D%29) from `java.util` package?

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 4};
double[] doubleArray = {1.1, 2.2, 4.4};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubleArray));
```

Comment: A good aproach, but I would need to control the format of the output

Comment: Use a find and replace text method. You could replace `", "` with `" "`, and then remove `[` and `]` characters to have the output you provided in the question.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.lang.reflect.Array` that allows access to elements of any time of array. See `get(arr, index)`, `getLength(arr)` etc.

Comment: And then his method signature would be `printArray(String title, Object intOrDoubleArray`)? Seems like giving up type-safety (and probably some runtime performance for the reflection).

Comment: @Thilo: Yes, true. That's what you get for using primitives in Java. Primitives really are, ehm, primitive in Java, and don't enjoy many of the benefits the "real" types do, such as polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your issue is this:

```
public class Test {

    public static String numberArrayToString(Number[] arr) {

        if ( arr == null ) return "";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for ( Number n : arr) {
            sb.append(n.toString()).append(" ");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer[] intArr = { 1, 4, 6, 7 };
        Double[] dblArr = { 33.44, 55.66, 11.22 };

        System.out.println(numberArrayToString(intArr));
        System.out.println(numberArrayToString(dblArr));

    }

}
```

It produces this:

```
1 4 6 7 
33.44 55.66 11.22
```

However, it only works if you define your arrays with boxed primitives (i.e., sub-classes of `Number`), but not with primitives (i.e., `int[]` and `double[]`).

The problem is that using boxed primitives is really inefficient.

Comment: how do you convert existing `int[]` and `double[]` to `Integer[]` or `Double[]`? [hint: code duplication]

Comment: That's the whole issue, you would have to create a new int[] and loop through Integer[], which is also totally inefficient. Reality is: you should implement multiple version of your method.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to create the string create the print method using an `Object[]` array as such

```
int[] intArray = ...;
String str = printArray(title, ArrayUtils.toObject(intArray));

double[] doubleArray = ...;
String str = printArray(title, ArrayUtils.toObject(doubleArray));

public static void printArray(String title, Object[] array) {
    return title + " " + StringUtils.join(array, " ");
}
```

Note, this internally will copy an array which will box the ints into Integer objects, so if performance/size of array is an issue I would bite the bullet and create methods for the primitive types, though I'd call all the methods `printArray` and overload it with different types.

EDIT:

Instead of commons-lang, you could use [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/index.html) primitives, which will not copy the array (but will just autobox the floats in the list), so you could do:

```
int[] intArray = ...;
String str = printArray(title, Ints.asList(intArray));

double[] doubleArray = ...;
String str = printArray(title, Floats.asList(doubleArray));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using guava you can convert the primitive array (int[]) to a List of the wrapper type (List) using [Ints](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html). Additionally you can use the [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).

```
Joiner.on(' ').join(Ints.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}));
```

The method is then:

```
void printIntArray(String title, int[] array) {
    printArray(title, Ints.asList(array));
}

String printArray(String title, Iterable<? extends Number> asList){
    return title + " " + Joiner.on(' ').join(asList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wrapper classes Integer and Double instead int and double. Write one Method using their base class [Number](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)

Comment: Unfortunatly we can't cast a `double[]` to `Double[]` (for example), so we'd have to create a new wrapper array and copy all values one by one - and for that, we'd have to handle each array of primitives separatly and create duplicate code ;) (btw - had the same idea)

Comment: Why the downvote. The answer is technically correct (though it may not be what the OP is looking for).